# iPhone - May an async NSURLConnection HTTP response interfer with running process?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I have a request :

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

that is launched.

When I receive at any time :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
```

I change the content of an array (remove or add items).

In another part of my program, I have to parse that array to work with its content.

So the question is : while I'm working with the content of the array ("for xxx in array" loop), may the response of the server (that can come at any time) cause the code of `connectionDidFinishLoading` change that array, and make the whole thing crash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and it will cause your app to crash. You can either work with a copy of the array that is being modified by the NSURLConnection delegate method OR wait for the method to finish before iterating through the items in your array.

Maybe block that particular operation while there is an active NSURLConnection so the rest of your UI is still usable.

Comment: When calling an async method like that one, is a new thread created for the delegate method ?

Comment: From the documentation: NSURLConnection’s delegate methods—defined by the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol—allow an object to receive informational callbacks about the asynchronous load of a URL request. Other delegate methods provide facilities that allow the delegate to customize the process of performing an asynchronous URL load. These delegate methods are called on the thread that started the asynchronous load operation for the associated NSURLConnection object. So if you started the NSURLConnection on the main thread, the delegate will be called on the main thread.

Comment: Ok, then as I only have one thread, what about the question asked. I gues that while I'm working on the array, the delegate method cannot be triggered, isn't it ?

Comment: Well once you started your NSURLConnection your only option is to stop the array enumeration until you receive the response and update the array. If you post the work you need to do with the array and give us some context around what needs to be done we might be able to come up with a different suggestion but from what you've told us so far, you should wait for the delegate response before iterating through the array, or make a copy of the array which you can use for anything you want, then update it once the response comes in from your delegate.

Comment: Or I can parse the areray assuming the delegate call will not happen during my work on that array. And let the delegate calls modify it after I've done my work. Isn't it ?

Comment: Well you have no control over when the delegate is going to get called so you will eventually run into problems.